# How to create a Spark dataframe with timestamp?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp

How can I create this Spark dataframe with timestamp data type in one step using python? Here is how I do it in two steps. Using spark 3.1.2

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema_sdf = StructType([ 
    StructField("ts", TimestampType(), True),
    StructField("myColumn", LongType(), True),
    ])

sdf = spark.createDataFrame( ( [ ( to_timestamp(lit("2022-06-29 12:01:19.000")), 0 ) ] ), schema=schema_sdf )
```

Comment: Copy-pasting gives an error. 
TypeError: field ts: TimestampType() can not accept object Column<'to_timestamp(2022-06-29 12:01:19.000)'> in type <class 'pyspark.sql.column.Column'>

Comment: do you mean you don't want to define a schema altogether?

Comment: @samkart: altogether would be also fine. I am search for the most compact way. In the web I'm mostly finding examples with withColumn command, which seems not short and neat to me.

Comment: I agree it's not nice to use additional functions. But mostly you don't need a real timestamp type. string type works well for Spark functions. I've provided an example in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PySpark does not automatically interpret timestamp values from strings. I mostly use the following syntax to create the df and then to `cast` column type to timestamp:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

sdf = spark.createDataFrame([("2022-06-29 12:01:19.000", 0 )], ["ts", "myColumn"])
sdf = sdf.withColumn("ts", F.col("ts").cast("timestamp"))

sdf.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- ts: timestamp (nullable = true)
#  |-- myColumn: long (nullable = true)
```

Long format was automatically inferred, but for timestamp we needed a `cast`.

On the other hand, even without casting, you are able to use functions which need timestamp as input:

```py
sdf = spark.createDataFrame([("2022-06-29 12:01:19.000", 0 )], ["ts", "myColumn"])
sdf.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- ts: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- myColumn: long (nullable = true)

sdf.selectExpr("extract(year from ts)").show()
# +---------------------+
# |extract(year FROM ts)|
# +---------------------+
# |                 2022|
# +---------------------+
```

Comment: How would the code look like, if I would like to have the current timestamp instead of the hand written time-string "2022-06-29 12:01:19.000"? Replacing the string with current_timestamp() does not work for me.

Comment: @Luk-StackOverflow for the current time you can use python's datetime module. `datetime.datetime.now()` can be used instead of the string `"2022-06-29 12:01:19.000"`

Comment: @samkart: it works. Thx, that is what I finally was searching for.